# How to make post request with AFnetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have to make a post request using AFNetworking library with following request parameters

```
{
"method":"validate",
"name":{
"firstname":"john",
"lastname":"doe"
}
}
```

How to make this request using latest version of AFNetworking v3  library?

I used the following code and it doesn't work

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{\"method\":\"validate\",\"name\":{\"firstname\":\"john\",\"lastname\":\"doe\"}};

[manager POST:@"http://myUrl.." parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject description]);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Im getting the following error,

```
    2016-02-13 11:04:54.085 SlideOutMenu[3698:50453] nulllllll
2016-02-13 11:04:55.794 SlideOutMenu[3698:50453] Failure Request failed: internal server error (500)
2016-02-13 11:04:55.795 SlideOutMenu[3698:50453] (null)
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I am sure there is enough guidance available for AFNetworking....but if you not read it than check https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: yes, I have updated my question with what I tried..

Comment: Sometimes a not so great server simply just says 500 error even though it is expecting a few more required parameters which it should tell the client. Might have to ask your server developer what the required parameters are if you haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already applied **[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]]** no need to convert dictionary to JSON again.

simply pass dictionary as a parameters, it will work.

```
NSDictionary *name = @{@"firstname": @"john", @"lastname": @"doe"};

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[parameters setObject:@"validate" forKey:@"method"];
[parameters setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
```

Also no need to initialise **NSURLSessionConfiguration** with **defaultSessionConfiguration**, AFNetworking will automatically initialise that. Simply use **[AFHTTPSessionManager manager].**

Comment: I'm getting ˚Request failed: internal server error (500)

Comment: What was the error when you tried with your own code ?

Comment: I got a failure message previously when I tried with my own code

Comment: should set the content type as json explicitly to avoid internal error?

Comment: Nope its not needed.
Update your question with output error, so that It'll help to solve your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103356/discussion-between-iosenthusiatic-and-stanly).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.Connect with your server guy.
code 500 is server side error.
check out this link for response code detail

http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html